# SOQL query for specific report

Tags: soql

Can someone please help me to write SOQL query to get all records for any custom report like "https://xxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com/00O0L000003q8C5" so here "00O0L000003q8C5" is my report id and i need to write SOQL query to pull all records for this report via SOQL. thanks

Comment: Reports cannot use SOQL queries.  You have to use filter conditions in the report to select the desired records.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write a SOQL query that returns results for any arbitrary report. Each report is different and would reduce to a different SOQL query.

You can use the [Reports and Dashboards API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_intro.htm) to programmatically execute report runs and extract the resulting data. This API is accessible in Apex or via the REST API.

Alternately, you can analyze each report individually and build a SOQL query that yields the same records as the report run.